# How to pass id as query string

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I want to redirect to new page when click on edit (href link) along this i want to fetch the data corresponding to the record.
this is view code

```
<tr data-view-key="<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <td class=""><?php echo $id; ?></td>
    <td class=""><?php echo $article_type; ?></td>
    <td class=""><?php echo $abbr_article_type; ?></td> 
    <td class=""><?php echo $journal; ?></td>   
    <td class=""><?php echo $prefix_article_no; ?></td> 
    <td>
        <a href="" name="edit_article_type">Edit</a>
        |
        <a href="#<?php echo $id; ?>" name="delete_article_type">Delete</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

this is js

```
    $(document).on("click", "a[name='edit_article_type']", function (event)
    {           
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location = "add-article-type-details";
    });
```

in controller i want to update the data

Comment: `<a href="edit?id=heresmyid">Edit</a>` What's the problem? No need for JS at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

send it with a query string:

```
$(document).on("click", "a[name='edit_article_type']", function (event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $.trim($(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(0).text());
    window.location = "add-article-type-details?id="+id;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', 'td > button.myEditButton', function(){
    url = 'add-article-type-details';
    id  = $(this).closest('tr').data('view-key');
    window.location = url + '?id=' + id;
)};
```

**EDIT:** As your id is a data-attribute in the tablerow, you listen to a click event of a button inside a `<td></td>`. On event it grabs the data-view-key attribute from the parent `<tr></tr>` and does a redirect to a given url and appends the id to it.

Comment: You should explain your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr data-view-key="<?php echo $id; ?>">
<td class=""><?php echo $id; ?></td>
<td class=""><?php echo $article_type; ?></td>
<td class=""><?php echo $abbr_article_type; ?></td> 
<td class=""><?php echo $journal; ?></td>   
<td class=""><?php echo $prefix_article_no; ?></td> 
<td>
    <a href=""<?php echo site_url('controller/function') ?>/<?php echo $id ;?>" name="edit_article_type">Edit</a>
    |
    <a href="<?php echo site_url('controller/function') ?>/<?php echo $id ;?>" name="delete_article_type">Delete</a>
</td>
```

You can use ajax as wel try this http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-edit-delete-and-update-data-without-refreshing-page-in-codeigniter/